# Dapper disposable instance with Ninject

Tags: c#, sqlite, ninject, dapper, dispose

I want to bind the database connection instance using Ninject and use it in scope of a thread in order to skip repeatedly typing the `using { var cn = new DbConnectionFactory() } [..]` whenever I need to make a query.

I have added a binding:

```
IOC.Kernel.Bind<IDbConnection>().ToMethod(ctx =>
{
    using (var cn = new DbConnectionFactory())
    {
        return cn.GetConnection();
    }
}).InThreadScope();
```

db factory class:

```
public class DbConnectionFactory : IDisposable
{
    private IDbConnection _connection;

    public DbConnectionFactory()
    {
        _connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=mydb.sqlite;Version=3;");
        _connection.Open();
    }

    public IDbConnection GetConnection() => _connection;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Now, this is working fine. One db connection is being created per thread, however, connection is being closed but not disposed!

So when I modify my `Dispose` method to do so:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    _connection.Close();
    _connection.Dispose();
}
```

The connection no longer seem to work properly and when accessed, throwing an exception: `ObjectDisposedException` Object is no longer accessible.

Question is: how can I bind and dispose the connection properly in Ninject?

Please note that I cannot use .InRequestScope() because this is not a web application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Ninject and other IoC containers, it is the container's responsibility to call `Dispose` on disposable objects. Unfortunately, with your implementation you are calling the `Dispose` yourself - and doing it incorrectly.

```
using (var cn = new DbConnectionFactory())
{
    return cn.GetConnection();
}
```

This code creates the `DbConnectionFactory` and creates a database connection. Then (due to `using`) it calls `cn.Dispose`. Your implementation there then disposes of the new connection you **just** created.

There are multiple ways of solving this, but the one I would suggest you starting with is to change:

```
public class DbConnectionFactory
{
    public IDbConnection GetConnection() 
    {
        var connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=mydb.sqlite;Version=3;");
        connection.Open();
        return connection;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
IOC.Kernel.Bind<IDbConnection>().ToMethod(ctx =>
{
    var cn = new DbConnectionFactory();
    return cn.GetConnection();
}).InThreadScope();
```

Then, as per the [docs](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes), the database connection will be automatically `Dispose`d when the underlying `Thread` is garbage collected.

Comment: While it works, one problem with that is, in C# you never know when the garbage collector gets in, therefore using a db connection from this binding will lead to database being locked: `Exception Found: Type: System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException Message: database is locked database is locked Source: System.Data.SQLite`

Comment: You tried my suggestion and that occurred @Lucas? Or are you saying it _might_ happen? How many threads do you have? How many times was `GetConnection` called?

Comment: Yep, tested that. I'm using async queries in tasks, so potentially many threads can be spawned. In this case 5 update queries were enough. Since I do not have `InRequestScope` method available (not a web application). I think I'd have to create own scope, in the near future I will move to .NET DI which works way better and has methods especially for tasks like this. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: In that case `InThreadScope` is a bad choice. You need to choose a different option. You could also use `Transient` - but in that case your code that uses the connection would have to take responsibility to call `Dispose` when it was finished with it.

Comment: Exactly. This is what I initially wanted to avoid. Using `Transient` is kinda pointless to be honest, when I'd have take care of disposing the connection myself anyways I think a better bet would be to use the conventional approach `using (var cn = _factory.CreateConnection()) { // make some queries and dispose }` because it's basically the same.

Comment: `Transient` is great for 99% of cases - since the vast majority of classes are not disposable.